# Apache won't cache some HTTP requests with wget, Perl or curl

Tags: perl, apache, http, caching, wget

I use Apache as a proxy server. It is used for caching. There's a problem with caching according to HTTP request.

When I use a proxy and either wget or Perl with LWP they send an HTTP request with a URL after `GET` in the header, like this:

```
GET http://www.google.pl/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: www.google.pl
Connection: Close
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

When I use curl with a proxy, or Perl or wget without a proxy the request is fine:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: www.google.pl
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

In the first case Apache doesn't cache the data. I read that `CacheQuickHandler` is responsible for that, but when I turn it off in `http.conf` it doesn't help.

My questions are:

1. Can I force Perl or wget to send a standard HTTP request (without a URL after `GET` in the header)?
2. How should I configure Apache to cache both types of request, and how will this affect the performance of Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Both forms of HTTP request are "standard", but a request to a proxy *must* contain an absolute URI, so only the first form is valid.

Comment: So why does curl send request without URI and it works. And how to "fix" apache.